# Changing canvas drawn image on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm really struggling with the changing of my canvas drawn image so I thought I would see if anyone could assist me on here or offer advice.

I've drawn a static flag in canvas, and I've also drawn a waving flag. I'm trying to get this flag to wave on mouseover.

I initially thought that I was going to have to create two separate files, one for the static and one for the waving aspect. Then save each of them as a jpg/gif image using window.location = canvas.toDataURL("image/");.

But I've just discovered that you can apparently do this all in the same file via jquery/hover. Which seems a lot simpler and a more efficient way of doing it.

Here is the code for the waving flag:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var flag = document.getElementById('banglaFlag');
    banglaStatic( flag, 320 );
    var timer = banglaWave( flag, 30, 15, 200, 200 );
};

function banglaStatic( canvas, width ){
//Drawing the Bangladesh flag.

    //Declaring variables that regard width and height of the canvas.
    //Variables C to L are needed for the waving function.
    var a = width / 1.9;
    var b = 200;
    var c = 7*a/13;
    var l = a / 13;
    canvas.width  = b;
    canvas.height = a;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var radius = 45;




};

function banglaWave( canvas, wavelength, amplitude, period, shading ){

    var fps = 30;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var   w = canvas.width, h = canvas.height;
    var  od = ctx.getImageData(0,0,w,h).data;
    // var ct = 0, st=new Date;
    return setInterval(function(){
        var id = ctx.getImageData(0,0,w,h);
        var  d = id.data;
        var now = (new Date)/period;
        for (var y=0;y<h;++y){
            var lastO=0,shade=0;
            for (var x=0;x<w;++x){
                var px  = (y*w + x)*4;
                var o   = Math.sin(x/wavelength-now)*amplitude*x/w;
                var opx = ((y+o<<0)*w + x)*4;
                shade   = (o-lastO)*shading;
                d[px  ] = od[opx  ]+shade;
                d[px+1] = od[opx+1]+shade;
                d[px+2] = od[opx+2]+shade;
                d[px+3] = od[opx+3];
                lastO = o;
            }
        }
        ctx.putImageData(id,0,0);
        // if ((++ct)%100 == 0) console.log( 1000 * ct / (new Date - st));
    },1000/fps);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any advice/assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure where your problem is. I did not see any event handling code, so I assume that's your question:

Define a function to "handle the mouse event". For example, if you want to move the flag when the user moves the mouse over it, define something like:

```
function mouseMove(event) {
    var mouseX,
        mouseY;
    event.preventDefault();  // stops browser to do what it normally does
    // determine where mouse is
    mouseX = event.pageX;
    mouseY = event.pageY;
    // do something useful, e.g. change the flag to waving when mouse is over flag
}
```

Then, register this function to be called when the mouse moves:

```
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove, false);
```

`canvas` is the canvas you paint the flag on, `"mousemove"` is the name of the event (many more exist, such as "mousedown", "mouseup", "mouseout" (leaving canvas), "mousewheel", etc.), `mouseMove` is the name of your function (the event handler, as it's called).

Events are a little different from browser to browser (and even browser version), so you might need to implement different event handler if you need it across browsers.

Hoping this helped...

Comment: Would the banglaWave function go just after the mouseX = event.page.X; moustY = event.pageY? Sorry, this is the first time I have done this.. Could you please show me in the JSfiddle?

Comment: Sounds like some groundwork... :-)  I guess the best approach is the following: (1) You need a loop which recreates your canvas, using `requestAnimationFrame`. This function will execute a function of your own, say `drawFlag` every time the browser redisplays your page. In `drawFlag`, first clear the canvas, then draw the appropriate flag. (2) Choose the appropriate flag depending on whether the mouse hovers over the canvas. There are mouse events `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` for which you should define handler functions (as above). The handler for `mouseenter` sets a boolean, the function...

Comment: ... for `mouseleave` clears the boolean. Your `drawFlag` function draws the static flag if the boolean is false (i.e., mouse outside of canvas) or the waving flag if the boolean is true (mouse inside of canvas). This will probably require you to change the rendering of your waving flag, from `setInterval` to `requestAnimationFrame`. -- If you google `requestAnimationFrame`, `addEventListener` and the mouse events, you should find enough examples and descriptions to put it together.

Answer (score 0):

canvas is like a sheet. there is no any object on which you can hover.
for doing what you wanted to do is just,bound an area on the flag,
follow the 'virtualnobi' answer and calculate if mouse co-ordinate falls on that region,
if true do what ever you want.
like

`if (mouseX<100 && mouseX>0 && mouseY>0 && mouseY<100){

//animate the flag

}`

use `mouseX=event.clientX;`
  `mouseY=event.clientY;`

bounded area is x=(0,100) , y=(0,100) here.